# About deleted questions already answered

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

This is my very first question in the metaworld. As known I'm not much connected to this parallel world, so I don't know about rules. One of them, a behavior that seems irrational to me:

*[Can one delete his question after receiving a proper answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413592/overloading-ostream-for-templates/49414638#49414638)*?

I'm not saying I resolved the OP's problem, but at least I could get rid of the interference at my end. Where he can just leave it there, unvoted, even unaccepted, it could help some one else.

If this question reveals improper/irrelevant/already-known or solved, I'd delete it before it gets answered or even closed.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that the answer should be upvoted/accepted to prevent deletion.

Comment: It can be frustrating, but it's definitely a risk when answering questions, usually when answering questions of newbies to the site and less likely well established members like the fellow who asked your original question.

Comment: well, if the answer is right it is shame to be thrown away a good answer that is in fact knowledge, that may help other in the future... so for me,i should say.. after your question is answered, is like in real life, you just CAN'T pretend you didn't ask